# Moderator icon (♦) bugs on profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderators

This is sort of a two-in-one bug.

I was viewing the summary tab on [Jarrod Dixon's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon#user-panel-accounts), and all his accounts were listed as they should be under "Accounts." However, he should be a moderator on all of these sites, and only Area 51 had the moderator icon (♦) next to it:

[image]

I clicked "view more" to see the rest of his profiles, and they all have the icon next to them:

[image]

I went back to the summary tab to find that it had fixed itself:

[image]

That's the first bug. Any reason this happened?

**EDIT:** This happened again in Chrome. Looks like it happens periodically.

And on to my second bug. You'll notice that the ♦ icon skips a line for every single site. Given that this is happening to all of them, is this by design?

Comment: After clearing my cache, I know see the view in your last screenshot consistently (was seeing the same thing as your first screenshot previously with Chrome). I'm guessing an update was pushed recently.

Comment: Reproduced this on my own profile.

Comment: Also reproduced on BoltClock's own profile.

Comment: @BoltClock: I went to your profile and you had no mod icons for SO or Meta. Refreshing the page fixed it. One strange bug.

Comment: Reproduced on Jarrod's profile on Opera 11.60 (all three steps), as well as on BoltClock's profile and [my own one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156902/paulo-ebermann). Looks like the summary only shows the diamonds after the account page has be loaded once. (And Area51 is always different.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The styling of the link in the account panel (in case of a *really* long site name) has an explicit width for the elipses overflow...so a span with the ♦ *after* that was creating another line.

This will be fixed in the next build.  I'll take a look at the mod status loading (without loading the accounts *tab* first)...we don't cache this at the network level, so it's not in the "cheap" call...we'll see if we can load this in a cheap way in the future.

---

*Update:* we have a plan here, there's some additional work we need to do in the background, but diamonds will appear in the panel as well as the tab correctly in the future.  This will backed by dogfooding our public API v2 ([currently in private beta](https://stackapps.com/questions/2701/api-v2-private-beta-begins)), so we'll be displaying the same data any third-party app could.

<s>It'll remain flaky for a bit (not displaying diamonds correctly unless someone hits the full tab for *that* cache load), but the result of being API backed will be better for all involved (bonus: and result in a faster accounts tab load, in the case of a cache miss).</s>

*Updated update:* The accounts views are now switched over to APIv2, diamonds should display everywhere correctly on the first load now.

Comment: Cool, "dogfood" can also be used as a verb. Something new I learned :)

Comment: Looks like the new line bug is resolved. Thanks! Though I'll hold on accepting until we get some more news on the first bug I addressed.

Comment: @Purmou - We're working on it...the work is actually almost done, we just need to test a bit before putting the full weight of SO on the new API (it's not a "testing" level load, ya know?) :)

Comment: @Nick: Sounds great. Thank you!