# In "Accounts" section of user pages, indicate which sites the user moderates

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-accounts, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Moderator icon (♦) bugs on profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115671/moderator-icon-bugs-on-profile)

I was looking earlier at the profile of a user I'm fairly certain is a mod on some site, but I couldn't remember which site. After investigation, it seems that

1. In the [StackExchange user profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts) accounts tab, we can see all sites for which a user moderates.
2. In the [Accounts tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts) on any particular site, we can see all sites for which a user moderates.
3. In the [User summary page](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts) on any particular site (which is the one you're most likely to see), we see on the top if they mod that particular site, but in the "Accounts" section a bit below that, we don't get an indication of whether they mod each site, except for Area 51.

Two things about this. First, since Area 51 does show the diamond and the others don't, this seems like a bug to me; it should be consistent. Second, I think it would be useful to see on the user summary page which sites a given user moderates for, so I suggest making all sites show the diamond if the user is a mod there. I also think the list should sort by mod status first, but that is perhaps a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).